# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Access denied. using JNI

Tags: tomcat, permissions, java-native-interface, windows-server-2008, tesseract

I'm struggling trying to make work a Java servlet that use Tesseract through the [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net) project. When the library main class (TessAPI) is initialized the servlet stops with the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Access is denied.

    com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    it.sampleProj.DocumentVisualizer.startOCRConfidence(DocumentVisualizer.java:301)
    it.sampleProj.DocumentVisualizer.startRecognition(DocumentVisualizer.java:220)
    it.sampleProj.DocumentIdentifier.recognizeDocument(DocumentIdentifier.java:147)
    it.sampleProj.DocumentIdentifier.startDocumentSearch(DocumentIdentifier.java:89)
    it.sampleProj.DocumentRecognizerServlet.doPost(DocumentRecognizerServlet.java:106)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

I'm using Apache Tomcat8 64bit, with JDK 7.0.60 64bit and Tesseract.exe and related .dll files at 64bit on a Windows 2008 Server R2 64bit.
This error sounds like a permission problem and  I'm not sure about what is the user account used by Tomcat to run. Anyway I have already granted all permissions to the two .ddl files which are included in the lib folder of tomcat (libtesseract302.dll and liblept168.dll)

There is a way to obtain more info about what are the resources interested by the Access denied problem?

Comment: Are there other dll that are being depended on by libtesseract302.dll and liblept168.dll?  They will also need a permission adjustment.

Comment: Maybe yes, but how can I discover if there are others dependent dll?

Comment: I usually use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was caused by a 32-64bit mismatch.

As I said Tomcat, JVM, Tesseract and OS was in their 64bit version. But the war had been generated with a 32-bit build setting.
Re-creating the .war for 64-bit solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc:

```
Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.
```

It is an error related to JNI. loadLibrary is trying to load the native library and it is not found on the path defined by java.library.path. This path should be defined as a system property when you start the JVM. e.g.

```
-Djava.library.path=<your native library>
```

Comment: Setting the path shouldn't make a difference, the library has been found and the error was thrown during the call to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

Run it as System Administrator and It will work for sure.